# linq to sql Cannot access a disposed object. Returning a new created object

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am simply creating a new object that has one to on relationship. A comment to a User relation.  When I try to retrieve the new object I get the error Cannot access a disposed object. I am not sure what is going on. Thanks for any help or suggestions.

```
     using (var db = new LinqEntityDataContext())
            {

                var comment = new Comment();
                comment.CommentBy = GlobalVariables.User.ID;
                comment.OutPutMessage = commentText.Trim();
                comment.PhotoID = int.Parse(pictureID);
                comment.CommentDate = DateTime.Now;
                db.Comments.InsertOnSubmit(comment);
                db.SubmitChanges();
                return comment;
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `return comment;` after the last  bracket.

You are finishing the function just before the Dispose, that's why you get the Exception

Something like this.

```
 var comment = new Comment();
 using (var db = new LinqEntityDataContext())
            {               
                comment.CommentBy = GlobalVariables.User.ID;
                comment.OutPutMessage = commentText.Trim();
                comment.PhotoID = int.Parse(pictureID);
                comment.CommentDate = DateTime.Now;
                db.Comments.InsertOnSubmit(comment);
                db.SubmitChanges();              
            }
  return comment;
```

Comment: I did that and I am still getting the "Cannot access a disposed object on the user property.

Comment: Debugging through the code, I looked at the object Comment.User I see 'comment.User' threw an exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException'

Answer (score 0):

So to understanding I guess with Linq to SQL you have to make two calls one to insert than another to get the data with the association. So In my code I just have two using statements the second one just calling to get the object of the id created (seems redundant to me). I hope that someone can post or direct this posting to a real solution.